# How can I run this function on hover?

Tags: jquery

How can I run this function on hover?

```
$cellButtonGroup.on( 'click', '.button', function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  $carousel.flickity( 'select', index );
});
```

This did not work:

```
$cellButtonGroup.on( 'hover',
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$cellButtonGroup.hover(function() {
  //your code here
});
```

or else you can use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` insted of above with following ways.

1st way

```
$cellButtonGroup.mouseenter(function() {
      //your code here
    });

$cellButtonGroup.mouseleve(function() {
      //revise your code here [ex: if your add some class in mouseenter, remove that in here]
    });
```

2nd way

```
    $cellButtonGroup.mouseenter(function(){
      $("your selector").addClass("thisIsanExample", function(){
      $("you selector").removeClass("thisIsanExample");
    })

});
```